# NavigationDrawer in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

i want to implement Navigation Drawer in windows phone 8. i found a project called `Drawer Layout` that implements Navigation Drawer in windows phone but it is compatible with windows phone 8.1 not 8. is it possible to port this project to windows phone 8?

Comment: You can always upgrade a project to 8.1, but not to downgrade.

Comment: i konw. i found project source code and try to make it compatible with windows phone 8 but some classes doesn't exist in windows phone 8 sdk

Comment: Most current navigation drawers (Slide in Menus, etc.) stop working once you start using ListView in your apps content. The ListView/WebView have a lot of optimizations but prevent other controls from using the touch events... Therefore we decided to remove the drawer for something else. Oh and: You will get A LOT of bad ratings in the store for using a drawer because its "too android"...

Comment: @KaiBrummund i am developing a mobile bank app that owner want to design the app with navigation drawer. i see two application that implement navigation drawer . 1 - Microsoft OneDrive app 2- theChive ( don't install this app. it has critical issue that prevent your phone from locking and unlocking )

Comment: Kind of: OneDrive just has a slide in menu, which is kind of easy to achieve. But it just toggles via the button. If you want it to slide in via touch over the edge, you will have to cope with some limitations (when using list-/gridviews, etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kai Brummund inspired me. Here's a port of `Drawer Layout` for **Windows Phone 8** -> https://github.com/jgannaway/windows-phone-navigation-drawer.

Note, I haven't tested this rigorously, just made sure it compiled and ran on an actual device.

Comment: tnx a lot. i will test it and make this as an answer if it works

Answer (score 2):

I also very much like the Drawer Layout for Windows Phone 8 at https://github.com/amarmesic/windows-phone-navigation-drawer, however, I can't seem to find out how to make the drawer open from right to left, not left to right as per the default.

Anybody got some ideas?

Answer (score 1):

SlideView works for Windows Phone 8 Apps.
https://slideview.codeplex.com/

Comment: i want solution for windows phone 8 not 8.1 . SlideView is like hamburger menu in android . i want a menu like navigation drawer - they are different

Comment: Sorry, did misread that. Edited the answer.
Slideview adds a top bar with the button, but you can just remove it in the style. They support touch as well.

Comment: [Drawer Layout](https://github.com/amarmesic/windows-phone-navigation-drawer) is exactly what i want but it is not compatible with windows phone 8

Comment: i want the menu opens over the current page not pushing the page left or right

Comment: Did you try porting it? Source is available and it is just one file. Don't even know if it needs any further changes other than adding SL namespaces.